# simple Panorama jQuery not loading with AJAX in Geomashup

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, panoramas

Hy i try to use the Simple Panorama Plugin in wordpress, loaded in a post trough AJAX with Geomashup.
Here the post loaded with geomashup and AJAX: http://bontex.mu/geo/

Unfortunately is the Panorama jQuery plugin not loading in AJAX.
According to the Geomashup author, i have to adjust the Panorama plugin to make it work.
I could not get any answers from the Panorama author how to fix it.
Are there any suggestions how to do that?
Thanks for answers.

link to the plugin: http://www.openstudio.fr/Un-viewer-de-panoramas-simple-en.html?lang=fr

Answer (score 0):

Just call `$("img.panorama").panorama();` after your ajax request is complete.

**For example:**

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
<script>jQuery("img.panorama").panorama();</script>
```